# Simple Multiplication with jQuery

Tags: jquery, multiplication

I can't seem to figure out out how to multiply 2 divs and display the total in another div. My several attempts were unsuccessful. For instance the end result would look like this:

```
<div class="itemOne">2</div>
<div class="itemTwo">5</div>
<div class="total">10</div>
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: jQuery seems like overkill for this.

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
var one = parseInt($(".itemOne").text(), 10);
var two = parseInt($(".itemTwo").text(), 10);
$(".total").text(one * two);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery here. In plain JavaScript try:

```
​var a = document.getElementsByClassName('itemOne')[0].innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('itemTwo')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(a,10)*parseInt(b,10);​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2cpnw/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhevp/)**

```
$('.total').text( parseFloat($('.itemOne').text()) * parseFloat($('.itemTwo').text()))
```